# How to Keep Form Data fields When Recaptcha is Invalid + App Engine Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, recaptcha

I've read this article, [Using reCAPTCHA with Google App Engine](http://daily.profeth.de/2008/04/using-recaptcha-with-google-app-engine.html), it wasn't very clear on how to keep the form data when the Recaptcha is invalid.

I've rough idea how to make this work through AJAX. But, is there a simpler solution ? As I don't really need AJAX as for registration. All I need is to allow user to reenter the captcha for invalid attempt, and retain the form data that user has entered.

Any advice ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is no simpler way/suggestions of doing this, I'm going to solve this using AJAX solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Send the received form data back to the form and set the form field values. WTForms can help you with validation and error messages.